# What is this VU-meter?

Tags: identification, multimeter, voltmeter

I just made a "home made" adjustable power supply and I want to attach a voltmeter to the output so I can easily set voltage using a potentiometer. I don't want to complicate my circuit with a microcontroller with ADC so I want to use a mini voltmeter.

I managed to get the following voltmeter:

[image]

The problem is that I have no idea how to use it as I don't understand that freaky scale and notations.

It only have two pins. I tried to connect to fixed power supplies but I can't correlate power supply voltages to value indicated.

Have you used something like this in the past? How to use it? How to place it on a circuit?

PS: It is very small, 25mm x 25mm
PS2: It does not have any code on it.

Comment: GOOGLE VU Meter......

Comment: It's a [VU meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VU_meter). Dunno what gave you the idea it is a voltmeter...

Comment: It is a VU (Volume Unit) meter - used in Audio consoles for measuring sound level.  The units it shows are decibels.

Comment: it's probably a linear movement meter, but scaled for vu. You should re-scale it, by opening it, replacing the cardboard scale with a linear scale of your choice, and then calibrating to read what you want.

Comment: @Neil_UK VU meter is a galvanometer. Unlikely to be used as voltmeter...

Comment: @EugeneSh. - And if you add a series resistor?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast A big enough will do. But just changing the scale won't work.

Comment: Hey, this will help: http://shaddack.brutowave.com/projects/method_VUmeterReuse/

Comment: I managed to do something adding a big resistor in series and I was able to vary from min to max from potentiometer. But definitely is not usefully as I cant view voltage. 
Hmmm...VU meter, well, this is embarrassing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine a lot of the comments...

That's a VU meter.  It has a highly non-linear scale, marked in decibels.

It looks like a normal moving coil meter, in which case it will work on DC, and the full-scale deflection is probably a few tens or hundreds of microamps.

If you really want to use it, you'll need another accurate voltmeter to calibrate it against.  You'll first need to work out what series resistor to add to make it read full scale at the maximum voltage you have.  This may be tens or hundreds of kilohms.

Then open the top, and replace the scale with a new paper one.  Carefully mark it at different voltages, as measured by the other meter.  Then take the scale out, mark it up neatly, and put it back in again.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments said, what you have is a VU meter, which (in simplified terms) displays sound pressure level.  This would work for some kinds of AC signals but definitely not for DC like you probably want to measure in your power supply.

If you can't find an [analog DC voltmeter](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=dc+voltmeter+analog&ia=images&iax=1&iai=http%3A%2F%2Fpreview.turbosquid.com%2FPreview%2F2014%2F07%2F10__22_28_22%2Fanalog_DC_voltmeter.jpg9b0b7cbd-8513-4d3f-b6ca-f63c31210635Original.jpg) there are still less-complicated options than a microcontroller, such as [this one using a comparator and some LEDs](http://electronic-projects.50webs.com/simple-led-voltmeter-circuit.htm).

Comment: As indicated by the link provided by @Eugene it could be used as a DC voltmeter.